# Where can I find the analytic formulas for the characters in a font?

Tags: fonts, bezier

I would like to create an animation starting from one of the characters (say $x$) in the standard math font in LaTeX. I am not a calligraphy expert, but I believe the characters are built by filling regions bounded by Bézier curves.
I would appreciate guidance on where I can find the analytical formulas for the characters in that font (I believe it's called computer modern).

I would also like to know how to get these formulas for fonts in general.

Thanks.

Comment: the METAFONT sources for Computer Modern can be found here: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/mf.

Comment: @plante Thank you for that, it does appear to contain the information I'm after. Now I need to learn how to decode these `.mf` files and convert them into parametric curves. Do you have any references for that by any chance?

Comment: there is the original METAFONT Book from Knuth, or you can look at one of the free online resources like http://metafont.tutorial.free.fr/